# If there is a repeated value in a column in excel, is there a way to have vlookup pass the first value and only use the second one?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using vlookup in excel to copy data from one column into another when a user enters a value.
The user enters a date in column Z, and vlookup searches for that value in column P, and copies over the corresponding x1,x2,y1,y2 values from columns Q,R,S,T into AA,AB,AC,AD. 
As you can see in these pictures, the date 8/1 pops up twice, and vlookup uses the first date's coordinates, when I want it to use the second 8/1's coordinates. 
[image: excelfile]

[image: excelfile2]

Is there a way to bypass the first repeated value and use the second one instead?

Comment: Not with `VLOOKUP`.  What if there are more than two identical dates?  You can use `LOOKUP` or an array formula with `INDEX/MATCH` to find the nth date.

Comment: I am new to excel formulas like this, how would one do this? (And there will not be more than two identical dates)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

The method below will return the **LAST** matching date.

For a formula solution, I chose to use Tables and Structured References:

```
AA2: =INDEX(Table1,LOOKUP(2,1/(Table1[[Date]:[Date]]=$Z2),ROW(Table1)-ROW(Table1[#Headers])),COLUMNS($A:A))
```

and fill right to `AD`

For a formula, without using the Table, you can use something like:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$P$2:$T$100,LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!$P$2:$P$100=$Z2),ROW(Sheet1!$P$2:$T$100)-ROW(Sheet1!$P$1:$T$1)),COLUMNS($A:B))
```

The advantage of the Table is that your reference range will auto-expand as you add rows to the table, so you don't have to either oversize it, edit it, or use dynamic range references *all of which have some issues*.

[image]